# Finding the limit of an integral expression

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals

> **Problem:** Evaluate $$\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{3}+h^4e^{\frac{1}{h^2}}}\cos^{3}x\,dx -\int_{0}^{\frac\pi3}\cos^{3}x\,dx}{h^4e^{\frac{1}{h^2}}}.$$

**My attempt:** First, I broke the first integral in the numerator with limits from $0$ to $\frac\pi3$ and $\frac\pi3$ to the other limit. Then the two from $0$ to $\frac\pi3$ cancel out and we are left with a single integral. Now, I used L'Hospital's rule and Newton-Leibniz rule in the numerator which gives me another difficult limit.

Can someone suggest an alternative path or maybe point out a flaw in my method?

Comment: What does the dot after  the Cosinus function mean? $$\cos^3(x).dx$$?

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be $\mathrm e^{\color{red}-\frac 1{x^2}}$ in the above expression?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner it was meant to be a central dot but I mistyped it

Comment: @Bernard Yes I'm sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that the integrand is periodic. You can reduce this problem to finding

$$ \lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{1}{t}\int_0^t\cos^3(x)dx.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $$\int\cos(x)^3dx=1/3\, \left( 2+ \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2} \right) 
\sin \left( x \right) 
+C.$$